# Make number representation selectable in matrix visual for specific values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, data-transform

I have the following report.

[image]

Here, the user has the option to select different values, which are then displayed in the matrix visual. Since the numbers are very large, I want the user to have the option to directly select whether the EUR figures are displayed in EUR or million EUR in the matrix. The `Sum Quantity` should always be displayed as usual, and for `Sum EUR` and `Sum DiffEUR`, the Power BI report user can choose how he want it to be displayed, either in EUR or million EUR.

Is there any way to solve this?

Here is a link to my test pbix-report: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6m3kjpqsn4efbsv6kcf09/StackOverflow-78001472-1.pbix?rlkey=fyo80t9zom17fewkskewo5v2t&dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the user selection :

```
SelectedValType = SELECTEDVALUE(ValOptions[ValType], "Sum EUR")
```

Then the EURorMillionEUR_Display measure which takes into account the user selection and displays the EUR and DiffEUR accordingly :

```
EURorMillionEUR_Display = 
VAR SelectedValType = [SelectedValType] // This is a reference to the SelectedValType measure
VAR SumEUR = SUM(valueData[EUR])
VAR SumQuantity = SUM(valueData[Quantity])
VAR DiffEURCalc = [diffValue] // This is a reference to the diffValue measure
VAR ConversionFactor = IF(SelectedValType = "Sum EUR" || SelectedValType = "DiffEUR", 1000000, 1)
RETURN
    SWITCH(
        SelectedValType,
        "Sum EUR", SumEUR / ConversionFactor,
        "Sum Quantity", SumQuantity,
        "DiffEUR", DiffEURCalc / ConversionFactor,
        SumEUR // Default to SumEUR if nothing is selected or recognized
    )
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not exactly what I want. I want two checkboxes directly over the matrix-visual, where the user can select between EUR or Mio. EUR. The default value here should be Mio. EUR. The columns in the matrix visual shouldn't be expanded. I only want to have the column 2023 and 2024, but these columns displayed in the right EUR-Value (EUR or Mio. EUR).

Comment: @MikiK do you really understand that the behaviour you are looking for is not possible in Power BI ?

Comment: Oh okay, so this is not possible. Thank you for your version, but then the answer to my question is now solved because it is not possible.

Comment: I gave a workaround :)